# saving array output into a join table (unpermitted parameter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the `Event` does get saved, but with `"artists":[]` blank, even though I selected multiple artists in the new form. 
the relevant part of the new form looks like this:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :event_artists do |fea| %>
    <%= fea.collection_select :artist_id, Artist.all, "id", "name", {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
  <% end %>
```

the log:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OEh0j/cp35s/FABhsETxeQKnqZCKXrbZMpeeEE6P+KSM3QVF94zIluB1rqAD65ci5CP+R6tQS8V1f3SXIQ6Vtw==", "event"=>{"name"=>"", "date(1i)"=>"2016", "date(2i)"=>"7", "date(3i)"=>"22", "date(4i)"=>"01", "date(5i)"=>"55", "description"=>"", "venue_id"=>"1", "event_artists_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"artist_id"=>["", "1", "2"]}}}, "commit"=>"Create"}
Unpermitted parameter: artist_id
```

here is this parameter is permitted in the controller

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:id, :name, :date, :venue_id, :description, { event_artists_attributes: [:artist_id] })
end
```

event_artist model looks like this:

```
class EventArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event, optional: true
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
  has_many :event_artists
  has_many :artists, through: :event_artists
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_artists, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

event controller:

```
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    if @event.save
      render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event
    else
      render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @artist = @event.event_artists.build
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `event_artists_attributes` inside of an unnecessary hash. Instead, use:

```
  params.require(:event).permit(:id, :name, :date, :venue_id, :description, event_artists_attributes: [artist_id])
```

But you have another problem. You're trying to set multiple artist ids on an `EventArtist` that `belongs_to` only one `Artist`. Because you have a `has_many artists, through: :event_artists` on your `Event` model, you can change the following:

Controller:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:id, :name, :date, 
                                :venue_id, :description, artist_ids: [])
end
```

And in the form, remove the `<%= fields_for…` block and replace it with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :artist_ids, Artist.all, "id", "name", 
                          {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
```

Comment: Can you dump your full params hash?

Comment: Can you update the post with your models? Is there an EventArtist join model that belongs_to :artist, and belongs_to :event? Can you include the accepts_nested_attribtues_for?

Comment: yep, check the post

Comment: Updated answer to use Event#artist_ids = […] instead of accepts_nested_attributes.

Comment: `Unpermitted parameter: artist_ids`, I need to get rid of the accepts_nested_attributes line completely? the result is the same whether with or without it.

Comment: What does your controller look like? No, you can still have the accepts_nested_attributes_for, it's just not used in this context.

Comment: I added the Event controller. What confuses me about your solution is that there is no mention of the event_artists join table anywhere in it. Where is Rails supposed to get the meaning of `:artist_ids` from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118043/discussion-between-sam-coles-and-sivanes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  params.require(:event).permit(:id, :name, :date, :venue_id, :description, { event_artists_attributes: [artist_id: []] })
```

Comment: not working. in the browser: `{"event_artists.artist":["must exist"]}`, in the console `(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with ActiveModel::Errors (0.35ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity`

Comment: That would be due to your blank element in the id array. You should remove `{include_blank: true} ` in your collection select.